# Image conversion in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-image

I am trying to pick an asset image -> base64image String -> Display it
But it is not working as expected. My code is as follows:

ImagePickPart:

```
ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(_images[_ran.nextInt(_images.length)]);
String asBase64 = base64Encode((bytes.buffer.asUint8List()).cast<int>());
Site site= Site();
site.image = asBase64;
```

The ShowImage part:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.grey[500],
            offset:Offset(0.0,0.0),
            blurRadius: 5.0,
            spreadRadius: 0.0,
          )],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft:Radius.circular(00.0),topRight:Radius.elliptical(75.0, 75.0)),
          image : DecorationImage(
            image: site.image!=null? Image.memory(base64Decode(site.image)):AssetImage('images/1024LowPoly.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover
          ),
        ),...........
```

I get the folowing error:

```
type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'ImageProvider<dynamic>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok found the answer.

I should use MemoryImage and NOT Image.memory!